# Is there a way to make this a switch case?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I know if I had one parameter I could do the switch-case but I have 4 and the third one needs to change.

```
if (GetoptionsetText("lead", "capg_calculatorutilized", 126350000, service) == "Section A")
        {

        }



        #region Advocacy

        else if (GetoptionsetText("lead", "capg_calculatorutilized", 126350004, service) == "Advocacy")
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region Partner

        else if (GetoptionsetText("lead", "capg_calculatorutilized", 126350005, service) == "Partner")
        {

        }
        #endregion
```

I can't find anything online that showed a way to do this when there are more than one parameters. My first thought was to create

```
string _a = GetoptionsetText("lead", "capg_calculatorutilized", 126350004, service)
```

But that won't work, I have tried. Should I recreate the function GetoptionsetText for each one with the new parameter. So it would be GetoptionsetText1(,,126350003)? Would that work?
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit] your question to remove all the unncessary code, to be left with just the `if` statements you're talking about?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. - equivalent here. Take out the not needed stuff.

Comment: The code works. I just want to know if this can become a switch-case because I have about 6 strings to match the function GetoptionsetText too

Comment: Your numeric values (the magic numbers above, e.g. 126350000) are changing in each case, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are calling a method to get the string and the 3rd parameter you are passing in those method calls is different in each case.

a switch statement will evaluate one result against each of the case values

> Each case label specifies a constant value. The switch statement transfers control to the switch section whose case label matches the value of the switch expression (caseSwitch in the example).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not get the value into a `string` first, then use a `switch` statement for that?

```
string value = GetoptionsetText("lead", "capg_calculatorutilized", 126350000, service);

switch(value)
{
    case "Section A":
        // ...
        break;

    case "Advocacy":
        // ...
        break;

    case "Partner":
        // ...
        break;
}
```

As an aside, why are you using strings to represent the type? It sounds like you might be better using an [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sbbt4032.aspx).